# Does Empowering an Ongoing spell double the −1 to cast spells too?

Tags: spells, cleric, dungeon-world

So if I were to cast Magic Weapon, which increases the damage dealt by one weapon by 1d4 and imposes a −1 ongoing to cast spells, and Empower it; would both the positive effect and the negative (−1 ongoing to cast) be doubled?

So is it:

+2d4 −2 ongoing to cast, **or**
+2d4 −1 ongoing to cast, **or** (though I think much less likely)
+2d4 −0 ongoing to cast?

The reason I ask is because I expect to be doing this in times of dire need and it would be good to know beforehand just what the spell will do.

Answer (score 9):

The spell only has only *one* effect: increase damage dealt by one weapon by 1d4.

I would rule that the -1 ongoing is the *cost* of the Magic Weapon spell, which is unaffected by empower.

The *cost* of the empower is having to choose one from the 7-9 list, so this bonus die has already been paid for. I see no reason for it to increase the *cost* of the base spell as well.

Comment: @IthilonethMoonsnow If this doesn't answer your question because you haven't told us relevant details, then please edit the question post to actually ask the question you have, including all relevant details. If this does answer your question though, consider marking it “accepted” by clicking the checkmark beside it. (In general, you will get better resulsts by asking real questions rather than fake questions that you think might give you an answer to your real question.)

Comment: Thank you for your kind suggestion. I am, truly, looking for the answer to the case of Empower as I need that foundation to build upon when considering my unique circumstances. These might or might not become part of a follow up question to be posted once I feel I have a satisfactory answer. I mentioned them, the circumstances,  in the comment above to try to encourage further discussion and perhaps because I got a little bit ahead of myself. Sorry about that. I have removed my comment.

I am still not satisfied with the answer though; it is one answer, not "the" answer if such exists.